# Issue custom list in android having loop in every row

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Here is my getter setter code for list item:

Java code:

```
   package com.example.listrestaurant;



public class Restaurant {

    private String RestaurantName;

    private String RestaurantLocation;
    private String restaurantCusine;    
    private String rating;
    private int iconID;
    public Restaurant(int iconID,String RestaurantName,String restaurantCusine,String RestaurantLocation, String rating) {
        super();
        this.RestaurantName = RestaurantName;
        this.restaurantCusine = restaurantCusine;
        this.RestaurantLocation = RestaurantLocation;
        this.rating=rating;
        this.iconID=iconID;
    }
    public String getRestaurantName() {
        return RestaurantName;
    }
    public void setRestaurantName(String restaurantName) {
        RestaurantName = restaurantName;
    }
    public String getRestaurantLocation() {
        return RestaurantLocation;
    }
    public void setRestaurantLocation(String restaurantLocation) {
        RestaurantLocation = restaurantLocation;
    }
    public String getRestaurantCusine() {
        return restaurantCusine;
    }
    public void setRestaurantCusine(String restaurantCusine) {
        this.restaurantCusine = restaurantCusine;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public int getIconID() {
        return iconID;
    }
    public void setIconID(int iconID) {
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }




}
```

Java code for showing list item:

```
 package com.example.listrestaurant;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int count=0;

        String ArrayColor[]={"DE1D0F","FC3B2D","FF7668","EFD816","FAE321","EDD614","9ACD32","689543","305D02","305D00"};

private List<Restaurant> restaurantList=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateCarList();
        populateListView();
    }
private void populateCarList(){
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rese","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","3.5"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","6.3"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","2.3"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","9.6"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rese","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","3.5"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","6.3"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","2.3"));
    restaurantList.add(new Restaurant(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Rest","Restaurant Cusine","Resturant Location","9.6"));

}
private void populateListView(){
    ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter =new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);;
}
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.item_view,restaurantList);;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
        Log.d("Position:", " "+position);
        View itemView   =   convertView;

        if(itemView ==  null){
            itemView =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        }

        //find the Car to work with
        Restaurant restaurantGetSetData=restaurantList.get(position);

        ImageView restaurantImage_restList_iv=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantImage_restList_iv); 
        restaurantImage_restList_iv.setImageResource(restaurantGetSetData.getIconID());

        TextView restaurantName_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName_restList_tv);
        restaurantName_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantName()+"count:"+count++);

        TextView restaurantCusine_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantCusine_restList_tv);
        restaurantCusine_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantCusine());

        TextView restaurantLocation_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantLocation_restList_tv);
        restaurantLocation_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantLocation());   


        TextView restaurantRating_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantRating_restList_tv);
        restaurantRating_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRating());
        String rate=restaurantGetSetData.getRating();
        restaurantRating_restList_tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+ArrayColor[(int) Float.parseFloat(rate)]));



        //-----------------------slot and offer--------------------------------------------------

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
                "helvetica_reg.ttf");
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
      LayoutParams layout=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
            params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantSlotOffer_restList_tv);


        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            l.clearDisappearingChildren();
            l.setLayoutParams(layout);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            TextView time=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            time.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.out_gray));
            time.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            time.setTextSize(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.custom_text_size));
            time.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            time.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
            View v1=new View(getApplicationContext());
            v1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            v1.setBackgroundColor(color.white);
            TextView deal=new TextView(getContext());
            deal.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            deal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            deal.setTextSize(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.custom_text_size));
            deal.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
            deal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.our_red));
            deal.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.out_gray));
            time.setTypeface(typeface);  

            //Log.d("slot from info anshul:", slot.get(j)+"\n");
            //time code
            /*{
                String hour=slot.get(j).substring(0, 2);
                String min=slot.get(j).substring(3,5);
                if(hour.equals("--")){
                    Log.d("hour is ", "-------");
                    time.setText("--:--");
                }else{
                    int hourInt=Integer.parseInt(hour);
                    int minInt=Integer.parseInt(min);
                    hour=String.format("%d:%02d", ((hourInt==0||hourInt==12)?12:hourInt%12),minInt);
                    Log.d("correct Time", hour);
                    time.setText(hour);
                }
                Log.d("hour:", hour);
                Log.d("min:",min);
            }
            deal.setText(offer.get(j));
            deal.setTypeface(typeface);*/

            //--remove this-----------------------
            time.setText("0:0"+j);
            //deal.setText("--");

            //-----------------------------------
            l.addView(time);
            l.addView(v1);
            //l.addView(deal);
            rl.addView(l);                  
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        return itemView;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return 8; /* where n is the number of row you want */
    }

}



}
```

Here is my xml code for each item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantImage_restList_iv"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantName_restList_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/restaurantImage_restList_iv"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"

        android:text="Restaurant Name"
        android:textColor="@color/tgred"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantLocation_restList_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restaurantName_restList_tv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurantName_restList_tv"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:text="Location Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantRating_restList_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="3.5"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantCusine_restList_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"


        android:text="Cusines"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/restaurantImage_restList_iv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurantLocation_restList_tv"
        android:textColor="@color/tabgray" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantSlotOfferLayout_restList_hsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurantImage_restList_iv"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/restaurantSlotOffer_restList_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurantRating_restList_tv"
        android:background="@color/tgred"
        android:text="Book Now"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is code for the list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="4dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/map_bt"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Map"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now my problem is that when I run this code and I got slot and offer in the code that is in loop for every row in list but it is appending when i scroll the list up or down. But I need to show only seven slot and offer.

At very first time when i run the code it  shows only 7 slot that is fine but when i scroll up or down it get updated and  shows 14 slot and go on.
Please Help me i put all of my effort but unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call rl.removeAllViews() every time in getView method that will stop adding slots each time.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
        Log.d("Position:", " "+position);
        View itemView   =   convertView;

        if(itemView ==  null){
            itemView =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        }

        //find the Car to work with
        Restaurant restaurantGetSetData=restaurantList.get(position);

        ImageView restaurantImage_restList_iv=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantImage_restList_iv); 
        restaurantImage_restList_iv.setImageResource(restaurantGetSetData.getIconID());

        TextView restaurantName_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName_restList_tv);
        restaurantName_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantName()+"count:"+count++);

        TextView restaurantCusine_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantCusine_restList_tv);
        restaurantCusine_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantCusine());

        TextView restaurantLocation_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantLocation_restList_tv);
        restaurantLocation_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRestaurantLocation());   


        TextView restaurantRating_restList_tv=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantRating_restList_tv);
        restaurantRating_restList_tv.setText(restaurantGetSetData.getRating());
        String rate=restaurantGetSetData.getRating();
        restaurantRating_restList_tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+ArrayColor[(int) Float.parseFloat(rate)]));



        //-----------------------slot and offer--------------------------------------------------

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
                "helvetica_reg.ttf");
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
      LayoutParams layout=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
            params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantSlotOffer_restList_tv);


rl.removeAllViews();//<------------------------------------------

        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            l.clearDisappearingChildren();
            l.setLayoutParams(layout);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            TextView time=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            time.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.out_gray));
            time.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            time.setTextSize(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.custom_text_size));
            time.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            time.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
            View v1=new View(getApplicationContext());
            v1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            v1.setBackgroundColor(color.white);
            TextView deal=new TextView(getContext());
            deal.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            deal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            deal.setTextSize(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.custom_text_size));
            deal.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
            deal.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.our_red));
            deal.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.out_gray));
            time.setTypeface(typeface);  

            //Log.d("slot from info anshul:", slot.get(j)+"\n");
            //time code
            /*{
                String hour=slot.get(j).substring(0, 2);
                String min=slot.get(j).substring(3,5);
                if(hour.equals("--")){
                    Log.d("hour is ", "-------");
                    time.setText("--:--");
                }else{
                    int hourInt=Integer.parseInt(hour);
                    int minInt=Integer.parseInt(min);
                    hour=String.format("%d:%02d", ((hourInt==0||hourInt==12)?12:hourInt%12),minInt);
                    Log.d("correct Time", hour);
                    time.setText(hour);
                }
                Log.d("hour:", hour);
                Log.d("min:",min);
            }
            deal.setText(offer.get(j));
            deal.setTypeface(typeface);*/

            //--remove this-----------------------
            time.setText("0:0"+j);
            //deal.setText("--");

            //-----------------------------------
            l.addView(time);
            l.addView(v1);
            //l.addView(deal);
            rl.addView(l);                  
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        return itemView;

    }
```

Comment: Also try not to do so many things in getView method for example have typeface created in constructor and use that instead of creating it in getView

Comment: Thank u very much.I was trying to solve this problem from last evening.

Answer (score 0):

oh I got it.

```
rl.addView(l); // this is problem.
```

you need to 'prevent' to add a View.
when you scroll up and down,

```
getView()
```

called again and again.

so

```
rl.addView(); // 7
```

rl.addView(); 7+7 
rl.addView(); 7+7+7 ...

prevent to add OR remove every time.
choose whatever you want.

Comment: Please elaborate i couldn't understand.